# Pass Radio button value to another PHP page in an array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a project on online test. I have pasted my code below. I want to collect the radio value of all question in an array and send it from index.php to checkAnswer.php. In this file i want to collect all user selcted radio value in araay so that i can compare it with array of correct answer. I want to compare both array for finding right and wrong answer.

this is json

```
[

      {
          "number": 1,
          "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op1"
      },
      {
          "number": 2,
          "question": " thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30 ,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op3"
      },
      {
          "number": 3,
          "question": " thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
          "op1" : 20,
          "op2" : 30 ,
          "op3" : 59,
          "op4" : 54,
          "correct_answer": "op3"
      }
  ]
```

this is index.php

```
 <?php
session_start() ;
$string = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$json_data = json_decode($string, true);

<section class="solve">
<div class="contianer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form action="checkAnswer.php" method="post">

      <?php
      foreach ($json_data as $key => $value) {
          echo
          "<p><span class='que'> Question</span>&nbsp;&nbsp". $value['number']."&nbsp;&nbsp". "<br><hr class='line'>". $value['question']."<br><br>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio'  name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1'>" ." " , $value['op1']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1'>" ." " , $value['op2']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1'>"." "  , $value['op3']."</pre>".
          "<pre>"."<input type='radio' name='question" . $value['number']."' value='op1'>"." " , $value['op4']."</pre>".
          "</p>";
      }
      ?>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
      <button id="">click</button>
       </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>

?>
```

this is checkANswer where i want array of radio values

```
<?php

$json_file = file_get_contents("example_10.json");
$json_decode = json_decode($json_file, true);
print_r ($json_decode);

$answer_array= array();

foreach ($json_decode as $key => $value) {
      array_push($answer_array,$value['correct_answer']);
}

print_r($answer_array)
$lengthOfJsonQuestion = count($answer_array);


 ?>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do. Your code to get the correct answers from the JSON looks fine for me. I haven't tested it yet.

So basically, what you need to do now is send the form to a PHP (you are doing that already to `checkAnswer.php` and fetch the correct answers of the USER via `Get` or `Post`. You have to add these into another array and then compare each value with the other array.

Important: your order has to match on both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In checkANswer.php file you can get form data by using [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

You can check what data is submitted by user using :

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
```

Then you need to compare this POST request data with your answer data.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i echo the array in body. As because of it is currently showing above the html tag as an comment. How would i acces its value

Comment: Are you talking about POST data that submitted by user?

Comment: Yes..its solved now. Suppose if someone left any question unfilld how to pass 0 value in post in that case ?

Comment: if(empty($_POST['question'])){ $ans = 0 }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to pass the complete array, just pass the selected value and compare it with the correct answer. You don't need to overcomplicate this.

Comment: but then i would have to add submit button on after every question...i want to send all those values i a single click of button

Comment: no, just put a submit button for your form and put all the input fields in your form along with a submit button, so when you submit, you'll get everything

Comment: create a form, put your fields and radio buttons in it, then in action put your checkanswer.php, based on your form method you can either use $_GET or $_POST to get the submitted form data